# Resolve stylus import file from webpack's resolve directory (absolute path)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, stylus-loader

**Versions:**

```
stylus: 0.54.5
stylus-loader: 3.0.2
webpack: 4.30.0
```

**Folder structure:**

```
src
 |_ css
    |_ base
       |_ _vars.styl
    |_ another.styl
 |_ js
    |_ some
       |_ some.js => (It has "import './some.styl'")
       |_ some.styl
```

- `import 'base/_vars.styl'` works fine in `some.js` works;
- It also works fine if imported in `another.styl` file. `@import 'base/_vars.styl'`
- However, it doesn't work inside `some.styl`. I've to use relative path to make it work `@import '../../css/base/_vars.styl'`

**Webpack Configs:**

```
const paths = {
  css: path.join(__dirname, '../src/css/'),
  javascript: path.join(__dirname, '../src/js'),
};

// module.rules for stylus loader
{
  loader: 'stylus-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: !IS_PRODUCTION,
    preferPathResolver: 'webpack' // Doesn't make any difference
  },
}

const resolve = {
  extensions: [
    '.webpack-loader.js',
    '.web-loader.js',
    '.loader.js',
    '.js',
    '.jsx',
    '.styl', // Doesn't make any difference
    '.css', // Doesn't make any difference
  ],
  modules: ['node_modules', paths.javascript, paths.css],
};
```

**Note:** Importing JS files and css from resolve directories work fine in JS file.

Interesting same webpack config for `sass-loader` works fine. **What's that I'm missing?**